# Storage::copy in laravel doesnt copy a Large file Perfect

Tags: php, laravel, php-ini, laravel-storage

I'm trying to copy a 10GB file to another directory in my local disk using this code
Storage::copy( 'file/test.txt', 'file2/dest.txt' );

But when I check it on the destination path it only copied 1.7GB out of 10GB.
It didn't show any timeout errors at all.
Is there any work around on this?

Comment: how much it takes to copy it? have you refreshed the directory to see how much it gets bigger or not?

Comment: how much it takes to copy this amount of data in seconds? can you measure the time? i think i got your answer

Comment: does my answer helped you? or what happened when you raised the execution time?

Comment: Hi @Abilogos thank you so much for your answer, I will give a try your solution today and will let you know if it has resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

as long as invoking php script will be happen with a request. a malicious code can turns system into an infinite loop, or an attacker (Danial of Service) can make a script run for a long time.

so to preventing this. PHP came up with some default setting which make it to not run for a long time period and **exit the execution** if some amount of time out passed and it didn't returned a response.

usually this times are sufficient. and its an **unusual case** you have to copy 10 GB file within **a script run**

> i suppose you have a regular HDD whit speed of about 60 MB/s for a
> execution time of 30 seconds, it will copy about 1800 MB. and it make
> sense with your evidence.

### Temporary fix

10000 MB / 60 MBps = 168 second. i come up with 180 second via a margin

in your **php.ini** , in **Resource Limit** Section, there are parameters for time out.
uncomment them and make them **180** seconds:

```
max_execution_time = 180
max_input_time = 180
```